# Programmatically get field values of term reference (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, field, taxonomy

How can I get a list of all the selected values ​​for a field?

For example I have a field called countries, and I want to get all countries selected for a certain node.

I need to have this list, because I want the region to be automatically selected in another field (regions), according to the chosen country.

Ex: I choose France in the countries, then automatically the European region is selected in regions

For now I can only copy the selected values ​​in the "countries" field, in the "regions" field, by doing this:

```
$node->field_regions = $node->field_countries;
```

Here is the result when I select France in the countries field :

Country: France

Regions: France

***Edit:***
I tried with the function:[field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7), but all I get is an array:

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_countries', $node->language);
```

Something is wrong? I also tried with this but I get the same result...

```
$items = $node->field_countries[$node->language][0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to another forum, I managed to solve my problem.

Here's how to read the content of my field countries:

```
foreach ($node->field_countries[$node->language] as $item) { 
    // Country id in Countries vocabulary
    $countryId = $item['tid'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it helped me in my searches.
I tried the function field_get_items(), but all I get is an array.